# htaccess redirect not working for inner pages / folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Ok, so I've got a stack of htaccess redirects from one domain to another, which for the most part works fine. However, this particular link isn't working:

http://giccampers.com.au/general-trailers/tipper-trailer/

It should take people to this website:

http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/

If you go to the main domain of http://giccampers.com.au/ it redirects fine. But I can't seem to get any of the other pages to redirect from that domain.

Here's what I've got (I didn't set these up, btw):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^giccampers.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.giccampers.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^giccampers\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.giccampers\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.blackseriescampertrailers\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.giccampers.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]

redirect 301 /general-trailers/tipper-trailer/ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://giccampers.com.au/general-trailers/tipper-trailer/ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/

RedirectMatch 301 /general-trailers/tipper-trailer/ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 /tipper-trailer$ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/
```

or

```
  RedirectMatch 301 /general-trailers/tipper-trailer(.*)http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/
```

Comment: That's not doing anything either :/

Comment: tried all 3 and still no go.. i'm sure under usual circumstances this would work, however, this website hates me and wants to be painful lol

Comment: i have tried this this is working fine here... first remove all other htaccess condition then try it

Comment: This site has hundreds of redirects, which i presume is the reason why it's not working.. perhaps its my browser, but i can't get it to work

Comment: add this line  RedirectMatch 301 http://giccampers.com.au/general-trailers/tipper-trailer/ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/

Comment: if you added then please tell me

Comment: It's been added

Comment: what's weird is if i add www to the start of the domain, it redirects fine.. but without it, it doesn't redirect.